# Unable to install git using homebrew

Tags: terminal, homebrew, git

I am trying to install git using homebrew:

`brew install git`

Terminal reads:

> ==> Searching for similarly named formulae... Error: No similarly named formulae found. Error: No available formula or cask with the
> name "git".
> ==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)... Error: No previously deleted formula found.
> ==> Searching taps on GitHub... Error: No formulae found in taps.

If I input `brew doctor`, I get the following:

> Warning: Suspicious https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core git
> origin remote found. The current git origin is:
> https://github.com/Homebrew/brew With a non-standard origin, Homebrew
> won't update properly. You can solve this by setting the origin
> remote:   git -C
> "/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core" remote
> set-url origin https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core

However, if i do `git -C "/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core" remote set-url origin https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core`, nothing changes and I get the same output with `brew doctor`

command line tools is installed:

`xcode-select --install`

> xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use
> "Software Update" to install updates

I have tried reinstalling brew, `brew update` and `brew cleanup`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you done `brew up` to update homebrew too?

Comment: Yes, tried this - still getting the same ```brew doctor``` output unfortunately

Comment: Even I had the same problem, in fact I'm unable to install any package using brew. Are you able to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the problem with homebrew but there are other ways to load git. [This link](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/install-git) lists several ways to load git. If you've loaded the Xcode comand line tools git may already be installed. Type `git --version` to see if git is already installed.  It was on my machine. The link also lists ways using MacPort.

Comment: Or just use the version Xcode provides

Comment: Yes you're right - git was already installed. I used the installer from the link you posted to get a more recent version without using homebrew. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

One workaround that works for me is running `brew search {formula}` before `brew install {formula}`.

In this case, run `brew search git` then `brew install git`.